# Assigning TestCases to TestFolders via Rally web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, rally

I have a situation where there are lots of test cases that don't belong to a test folder. This  is fine, but I'd like to write an application to move these 'orphaned' test cases into a test folder (mostly so it's easy to easily see how the tests are doing)
All of the test cases and the test folder I create are in the same project, but I get the following errors;

**Validation error: TestFolder.TestCases is an invalid relationship. One or more of the artifacts is in a different project.**

**Validation error: TestCase.TestFolder is an invalid relationship. One or more of the artifacts is in a different project.**

These seem to be telling me that I am assigning the test cases to a test folder in a different project - but they aren't.
Here's a snip of the code - m_currentRallyProject and m_workspace have already been set by a different method

Any thoughts?

```
public void CreateTestFolderForOrphanedTestCases(HierarchicalRequirement aUserStory, List<TestCase> testCases)
    {
        TestFolder myNewTestFolder = createTestFolder(aUserStory.Name);
        for (int i = 0; i < testCases.Count; i++)
        {
            TestCase myTestCase = (TestCase)testCases[i];
            myTestCase.TestFolder = myNewTestFolder;
            OperationResult myResult =  m_rallyService.update(myTestCase);
            if (hasErrors(myResult))
            {
                updateStatus("Could not set Test Folder for " + myTestCase.FormattedID);
                printWarningsErrors(myResult);
            }
            else
            {
                updateStatus("updated test case " + myTestCase.FormattedID);
            }
        }
    }

    private TestFolder createTestFolder(String testFolderName, TestFolder aParentTestFolder = null)
    {
        TestFolder myNewTestFolder = new TestFolder();
        myNewTestFolder.Name = testFolderName;
        myNewTestFolder.Project = m_currentRallyProject;
        myNewTestFolder.Workspace = m_workspace;

        CreateResult createTestFolderResult = m_rallyService.create(myNewTestFolder);
        if (hasErrors(createTestFolderResult))
        {
            // something went wrong
            Console.WriteLine("Could not create Test Folder");
            printWarningsErrors(createTestFolderResult);
        }
        else
        {
            myNewTestFolder = (TestFolder)m_rallyService.read(createTestFolderResult.Object);
            return myNewTestFolder;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you certain they're in the same project? Being in the same Project Hierarchy doesn't count. I.E. a Test Folder that is in a Child Project of the current Project, even with child scoping down = true, counts as being in a different Project. Try adding some logging that outputs the Project Name or ref for both the Test Case and the Target Test Folder.

Comment: By way of testing, I just ran a code sample very similar to yours where I re-assigned Test Cases that have no Test Folder, to a Test Folder in the same Project - it succeeded.

Then I deliberately tried re-assigning some additional "Folder-less" Test Cases to a different Test Folder that I confirmed is in a different Project, and received the exact same error message as you describe above.

Comment: Finally, if you add some logging that outputs Project metadata for both TestCase and target TestFolder, make sure to output both Name and ref - since Project Name is not guaranteed to be unique (different Rally Projects can have the same Name).

Comment: You are right, they were in different projects after all. I had debugged the anems only to find that there were two similar ones. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Dropping an answer in from the comments above :)

Make certain they're in the same project - you shouldn't get this message if they are. Being in the same Project Hierarchy doesn't count. I.E. a Test Folder that is in a Child Project of the current Project, even with child scoping down = true, counts as being in a different Project. Try adding some logging that outputs the Project Name or ref for both the Test Case and the Target Test Folder.

If you add some logging that outputs Project metadata for both TestCase and target TestFolder, make sure to output both Name and ref - since Project Name is not guaranteed to be unique (different Rally Projects can have the same Name).